# Invoice Counter Referencing Previous Worksheet Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need code that generates invoice numbers sequentially over a workbook of 60 worksheets. The current workbook is set up with a cover page that has "0000" in cell D3. The goal is for the code to cycle through all the worksheets and enter the next number in sequence into cell D3 based on the previous worksheet (0001,0002,0003,...).

I am currently working with the below code, half my creation and half pieced from research I was doing on referencing prior worksheets.

```
Sub InvoiceCounter()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Application.Volatile

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If IsEmpty(Range("D3").Value) = True Then
            i = rCell.Cells(1).Parent.Index
            PrevSheet(D3 + 1) = Sheets(i - 1).Range(rCell.Address)
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

My reasoning for using "If IsEmpty" is so the code skips the cover page that will always have a value in it (this will be manually entered depending on the type of invoice).

Any suggestions or contributions are appreciated.

Thank you,

Sean

Comment: Where are you defining `PrevSheet` and `rCell`?

Comment: The source I was using did not define. I initially thought that was an issue but I did not get an error from running the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the versions bellow

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InvoiceCounter1()    'If cover page is the first Tab (leftmost)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Previous Is Nothing Then         'Or If ws.Name <> "Coveer Page" Then
            ws.Range("D3").Value2 = Val(ws.Previous.Range("D3").Value2) + 1
            ws.Range("D3").NumberFormat = "0000"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub InvoiceCounter2()    'If cover page is after other Tabs
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tabID As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("D3").Value2 <> "0000" Then    'If Len(ws.Range("D3").Value2) = 0 Then
            tabID = tabID + 1
            ws.Range("D3").Value2 = tabID          'Or ws.Index - 1 vs ws.Index - 2
            ws.Range("D3").NumberFormat = "0000"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub InvoiceCounter3()    'If cover page is the first Tab (leftmost)
    Worksheets.Select
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Formula = "=wsID()"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0000"
End Sub

Public Sub InvoiceCounter4()    'If cover page is the first Tab (leftmost)
    Worksheets.Select
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Formula = "=wsID()"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.FillAcrossSheets Range:=Selection, Type:=xlAll
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0000"
End Sub

Public Function wsID() As Long
    If IsObject(Application.Caller) Then wsID = Application.Caller.Parent.Index - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Paul,
Thank you so much, InvoiceCounter1 worked perfectly. 10/10.
Sean